# sqlite jdbc resultset last

Tags: sqlite, jdbc

I have an application that uses the SQLite JDBC. I have a problem. I need to do the following code:

```
resultset.last();
int rows = resultset.getRow();
resultset.beforeFirst();
```

When I execute the beforeFirst method, I get an error to the effect that I can't position backwards. How do I get around this? Is there some way I can change my query so that the position can be shifted back?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite computes result records on the fly; the result set never exists as a complete data structure.

You could execute the query twice, or read all records into a temporary list, or execute a separate `SELECT COUNT(...) FROM ...` query beforehand.